# How can I customize Ionic plugins?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm using barcodescanner plugin for an app and want to customize some parts of the plugin so I try working directly inside the `plugins` > `com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner`dir so I make changes to `res` (layouts) or to `src` dir (the java files) but no changes are updated in my app when running it on device, I'm trying running from android studio and intellij but no changes appear, I also tried:

```
 ionic run android
```

Nothing changes.

Now I saw possible solutions in [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-plugin-not-updating/4422/2) I tried  `ionic build android` or `cordova prepare android`. Fromom the `plugins` dir then once again `ionic run android`; nothing changes...

I even tried deleting android.json (as recommended in link) in `plugins`dir but that just messes up the project.

This is my project structure:

[image]

Inside LibraryProject are the res and src dirs I want to customize stuff in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `plugins` folder you can find the plugins installed on your project.
When you add a platform with `cordova platform add android` or `ionic platform add android` the plugins will be installed in the platform starting from that folder `plugins`.

You could remove the platform and then add:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

Depending what you edited, you could need to rebuild some libs. Some months ago I needed change the window scanning size for the same barcode scanner plugin. [In this issue on github I found all instructions to do that](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/issues/130).

Comment: which of the solutions there seem to be more than one currently trying the first one, anyways thanks for the link I'll update if any works